# form errors do not show on the template

Tags: python, django

Non of my validation errors show, the template page just refreshes if there is something wrong. i placed the validation error code in my forms.py, i don't know if i am supposed to place it in my views, because nothing works. i also thought django had a default for errors, seems i was wrong.

html

```
   <form method="post">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <form method="post">{%csrf_token%} {{form.username}} {{form.first_name}} {{form.last_name}} {{form.email}} {{form.phonenumber}} {{form.state}} {{form.next_of_kin}} {{form.dob}} {{form.address}} {{form.password1}} {{form.password2}}
            <li class="btnn"><button type="submit" class="conf">Add</button></li>
        </form>
        {% if form.errors %} {% for field in form %} {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p> {{error}} </p>
        {% endfor %} {% endfor %} {% endif %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PatientForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Last Name')
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='address')
    next_of_kin = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Next of kin')
    dob = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Date of birth')
    state = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='State')
    phonenumber = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, help_text='Enter Phone number')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=150, help_text='Email')
    
    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'placeholder': ('Username')})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'placeholder': ('Email')})
        self.fields['address'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Address')})
        self.fields['phonenumber'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Phone number')})
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('First name')})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'placeholder': ('Last name')})
        
        

        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': ('Password')})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': ('Repeat password')})
        self.fields['dob'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': ('Date of birth')})
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': ('State')})
        self.fields['next_of_kin'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': ('Next of kin')})
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['phonenumber'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['address'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['dob'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['next_of_kin'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log'})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log swiy'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'log swiy'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phonenumber',
                  'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'address','dob','state','next_of_kin')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PatientForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match!')
    
    # Add this to check if the email already exists in your database or not

    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email is already in use! Try another email.')
        return email
       
     # Add this to check if the username already exists in your database or not     
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if username and User.objects.filter(username=username).exclude(email=email).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This username has already been taken!')
        return username
```

views.py

```
def addpatient(request):
    form = PatientForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.refresh_from_db()
        user.profile.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.profile.last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.profile.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user.profile.state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
        user.profile.dob = form.cleaned_data.get('dob')
        user.profile.next_of_kin = form.cleaned_data.get('next_of_kin')
        user.profile.address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
        user.profile.phonenumber = form.cleaned_data.get('phonenumber')
        user.is_active = True

        user.save()


        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(username, password, user)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(f'/dashboard/profile/{user.profile.slug}/{user.pk}')
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
    return render(request, 'core/addpatient.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `views.py` file, specifically, with your check for form valid.

In case of POST, you check if your form is valid, if it is not valid, you create a new form and pass it as contaxt to render method.

```py
if form.is_valid():
   # do if valid form stuff
else:
  # this gets executed every time form is not valid
  # if form is not valid, this will create a new form and return it, not existing form. 
  form = PatientForm()
return render(request, 'core/addpatient.html', {'form': form})
```

You can solve your problem by removing the `else` clause and returning the form without creating a new one. Something like this

```py
 form = PatientForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # if stuff
 return render(request, 'core/addpatient.html', {'form': form})
```

**or**
you can check if method is `POST' by doing something like this

```py
 def addpatient(request):
    if request.method == "POST"
       form = PatientForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
        # if  form valid stuff
       return render(request, 'core/addpatient.html', {'form': form})
    
    # this gets executed in case of get method
    form = PatientForm()
    return render(request, 'core/addpatient.html', {'form': form})
```